# How can I insert a "null" timestamp with Spring JDBC Framework into a DB2 database

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

I created a Java web application, in which I use the Spring JDBC Framework, in order to write my queries for the DB2 database. So far all the queries are working excellent.

I tried today to create an INSERT query for a table I have in my database. The query is really straight forword, it works as DB2 query and it looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO MYDB.USERSUBSCRIPTION (USERNAME, SUBSCRIPTIONDATETIME, UNSUBSCRIPTIONDATETIME)
VALUES('JamesTheBoss', '2017-07-07 07:07:07.007', null);
```

In my Java class I created the following methods:

```
private Timestamp getCurrentDateTimeInTimeStamp() {
        LocalDateTime currentDateAndTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        currentDateAndTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS.mm")).replaceAll("T", " ");
        Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(currentDateAndTime);      
        return timestamp;
    }

public void insertNewUserToDatabase(String username){    
        Timestamp  timestamp = getCurrentDateTimeInTimeStamp();
        String SQL = "INSERT INTO MYDB.USERSUBSCRIPTION (USERNAME, SUBSCRIPTIONDATETIME, UNSUBSCRIPTIONDATETIME) " +
                     "VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
        this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL,new Object[] { username, timestamp, null});
    }
```

My first query was the following:

```
public List<UserSubscription> getAllUserSubscriptions() throws SQLException {
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM MYDB.USERSUBSCRIPTION";
        this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        List<UserSubscription> userSubscription = jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL, new UserSubscriptionMapper());
        return userSubscription;
    }
```

and it works fine, as all other queries I wrote also  do.

When I try to insert "null" as a Timestamp Parameter in the query, I become an exception.

How can I insert a "null" value for a Timestamp by using the Spring JDBC Framework?

I would really appreciate having a feedback.

Comment: You'll need to let us know what the exception is. And how your database tables are defined. Is the Timestamp column defined as nullable in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been debbuging for a while and I found out that I can hardcode a null in my query and then the query works fine.

With a hardcoded "null" the query looks like this:

```
public void insertNewUserToDatabase(String username){    
        Timestamp  timestamp = getCurrentDateTimeInTimeStamp();
        String SQL = "INSERT INTO MYDB.USERSUBSCRIPTION (USERNAME, SUBSCRIPTIONDATETIME, UNSUBSCRIPTIONDATETIME) " +
                     "VALUES(?, ?, null)"; // <--- Hard Coded "null"
        this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL,new Object[] { username, timestamp});
    }
```

When this query is executed, I become a new record in DB2 Database with a "null" value for column "UNSUBSCRIPTIONDATETIME".